# Solivng differential equation by subtracting Y.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = y + 2$$ And normally u would isolate the y's and the x's but what if I subtract y and then solve the equation. That would like the following. $$ \frac{dy}{dx} - y =2 $$ $$ 
 \int(\frac{dy}{dx} - y)dx = \int2dx$$ $$ \int\frac{dy}{dx}dx - \int ydx = \int 2dx $$ $$ \int1dy - \int ydx = \int2dx $$ $$ y - yx = 2x + C$$ $$ y = \frac{2x+C}{1-x}$$ But when you check this u get an equation where your only solution that works is when x=0. What am is wrong with the math.

Comment: the integral of y with respect to x is not $yx$ since y is a function of x.Try $\int \frac{dy}{y+2}  = \int dx $ so that you are integrating y with respect to y.

Comment: To recognize the problem with what you are doing, remember that the integral is the opposite of the differential.  Now, you have said that $\int y\,dx = yx$.  However, if that were true, then differentiating $yx$ should give you $y\,dx$, but that is not the case.  $d(yx) = y\,dx + x\,dy \neq y\,dx$.

Comment: yes, now I see ty both.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = y + 2$$
you should  do
$$\frac{dy}{y+2}=dx$$
and then integrate
$$\log(y+2)=x+C$$
$$y=e^{x+C}-2$$

Comment: yes, I know how to solve it correctly. I want to know what is wrong with my logic. Because technically it looks right but something has to be wrong.

Comment: @RaghavBansal If you know how to solve it correctly, then solve it! Did I waste my time?  Paul has already written one of your mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} - y =2$$
Multiply by $e^{-x}$ then you can integrate both sides:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^{-x} - ye^{-x} =2e^{-x}$$
$$\int \left(\frac{dy}{dx}e^{-x} - ye^{-x}\right)dx =2\int e^{-x} dx$$
$$\int (ye^{-x})'dx =2\int e^{-x} dx$$
$$\int d(ye^{-x}) =2\int e^{-x} dx$$
$$ye^{-x}=-2 e^{-x} +C$$
$$y(x)=-2+ Ce^{-x} $$